# Postgres : lag and lead with special conditions

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, lag, lead

Forgive what may be a silly question, but I'm not much of a database guru.

Here is **my table** :

```
id_data | val_no3 | id_prev | id_next
--------+---------+---------+----------
1       |         |         | 2
2       |  7      |         | 
3       |         | 2       | 4
4       |  5      |         | 
5       |         | 4       | 10
6       |         | 4       | 10
7       |         | 4       | 10
8       |         | 4       | 10
9       |         | 4       | 10
10      |  8      | 4       |
```

In the table below :

- id_prev is the value of the id_data which precedes when val_no3 is null
- id_next is the value of the id_data which folow when val_no3 is null

And now **i would like to have this one** :

```
id_data | val_no3 | id_prev | id_next  | val_prev | val_next
--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------
1       |         |         | 2        |          | 7 
2       |  7      |         |          |          |    
3       |         | 2       | 4        | 7        | 5
4       |  5      |         |          |          |
5       |         | 4       | 10       | 5        | 8
6       |         | 4       | 10       | 5        | 8
7       |         | 4       | 10       | 5        | 8
8       |         | 4       | 10       | 5        | 8
9       |         | 4       | 10       | 5        | 8
10      |  8      |         |          |          |
```

The conditions are as follows:

**If val_no3 is null** then : val_prev and val_next must be null

**If val_no3 is not null** then :

- val_prev must be equal to the previous value of val_no3 (it should be null if val_no3 which precedes is null too)
- val_next must be equal to the following value of val_no3 (it should be null if val_no3 which folows is null too)

---

I think i might have to use something with lag and lead but i don't know how to do.

I would be very grateful if you could give me your help to resolve this issue, thank you.

Comment: And what have yout tried ?

Comment: I tried this but the result is not good : SELECT id_data,val_no3 , LAG(val_no3) OVER () , LEAD(val_no3) OVER () FROM b order by id_data
I see what should be the logic of the application but I do not know how to write it in SQL postgres.

Comment: You should post your attempts on your question.

Comment: NB I wouldn't store `id_prev` and `id_next` but derive them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for analytic functions, just sub-selects. Something like the following (untested) should work:

```
select
  id_data,
  val_no3,
  id_prev,
  id_next,
  (select val_no2 from b where id_data = x.id_prev) as val_prev,
  (select val_no2 from b where id_data = x.id_next) as val_next
from
  b x
order by
  id_data;
```

Comment: Its great ! Thank you very much Colin :-)